# Android :How to save favorite data to view list view

Tags: android

I am developing a TV/Radio app. I want to be able to save the favorite stations somewhere for the app and then load them into a list view under the favorites menu.

What is the best option to store this sort of data? For each station I want to store its Name, URL, and Descritpion.

I am thinking of using Shared Preferences and save the data in json encoded array. Do you think this is a good option?

Comment: To much opinion here in this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not a good option. Even though it seems like favorite radio stations are preferences, they probably aren't. What if I have 10 favorite radio stations. How will you manage that with SharedPreferences? I would strongly suggest you use SQLite with a table of favorites or another android way to persist data: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html